How to use the pose prediction of OpenXR to obtain predicted HMD pose?
I am developing a native OpenXR application. The render frame needs to be transmitted to the client through the network, and inevitably, there will be a delay. I plan to use pose prediction to reduce latency. However, it seems that method 1 and method 2 have no differences. What is the best way to utilize the pose prediction of OpenXR to obtain the predicted pose of the head-mounted display (HMD)?
int64_t currentTimeNs = currentTimeNs();
int64_t PredictedThresholdTimeNs = 30 * 1000 * 1000; // 30 milliseconds

int64_t predictedDisplayTime = currentTimeNs; // method 1
int64_t predictedDisplayTime = currentTimeNs + PredictedThresholdTimeNs; // method 2

xrLocateSpace(view_space, stage_space, predictedDisplayTime, &viewSpaceLocation);


I got the fail reason, I couldn't use Unix time, instead I should use OpenXR runtime epoc time.

Future pose prediction is done on a best-effort basis. 30 milliseconds may be too long of a future timeframe for the system to calculate an accurate prediction.
You could try with smaller time increments. The results will always vary from platform to platform. It is also possible that your particular system makes no future pose prediction at all.
